# Is it possible to initalize the layers in the neural newtworks first and add activations later?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, keras-layer, tf.keras, tensorflow2.x

for example, I have a sequential model with three layers.

```
model_loc = tf.keras.Sequential()
```

This below snippet is the usual way I add layers to the model and apply activation

```
model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=3, activation=tf.nn.tanh))
model.add(Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.tanh))
model.add(Dense(4))
```

Is it possible to apply activation function after each layer is added? Something like below :

```
model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=3))
model.add(activation=tf.nn.tanh))

model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(activation=tf.nn.sigmoid))

model.add(Dense(4))
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly why keras provides the `Activation` layer:

```
model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=3))
model.add(Activation("tanh"))

model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))

model.add(Dense(4))
```

EDIT

---

In case you want to use custom activations, you can use one of three different methods.

Assume you are redefining sigmoid:

```
def my_sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + tf.math.exp(-x))
```

1. Use `Activation` layer:

   ```
   model.add(Activation(my_sigmoid))
   ```
2. Use a `Lambda` layer:

   ```
   model.add(Lambda(lambda x: 1 / (1 + tf.math.exp(-x))))
   ```
3. Define a custom `Layer`:

   ```
   class MySigmoid(Layer):

       def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
           super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

       def call(inputs, **kwargs):
           return 1 / (1+tf.math.exp(-inputs))

   model.add(MySigmoid)
   ```

Method 3 is especially useful for parametric activations, like `PReLU`.

Method 2 is a quick fix for testing, but personally, I like to avoid it.

Method 1 is the way to go for simple functions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but what if I'd want to use a custom activation? Could I just define it in this way? : "model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=3))
model.add(Activation(custom_activation))" . I am getting a solution but I am not sure whether it is using my 'custom_activation' function or calling a default activation from the Activation layer in Keras?